# Reduce the size of photo sent with Messages.app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, photos, messages

When using Apple’s [*Mail.app*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Mail), a mail message offers a pop-up menu to reduce the size of an enclosed image.

➥ How can I do the same when shooting and sending photos from within [*Messages.app*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messages_(Apple)) on an iPhone?

Currently my iPhone sends out huge 3.3 meg files where 120K would do.

Comment: Hi! I find wikipedia links slightly odd. Is there some reason ? I assume that anyone answering or looking for answers knows what they are.

Comment: @ankiiiiiii I don't make that assumption. Newbies are born everyday. When I trek over to [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) to read about [BSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution), what many authors there consider to be mundane will be quite befuddling to me. Furthermore, time moves quickly in the computer biz; what seems commonplace today will soon be obscure tomorrow. “Can you find the VGA adapter for the ADC cable, that short SCSI cable, and hockey-puck mouse while I move this CRT?”

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on popup asking for file size, but in Messages settings, Low image quality mode can be turned on. See last option in Settings -> messages It will be set for all images.

Comment: How to set this low quality image mode?

Comment: Last option in Settings -> messages

Answer (score -1):

You can open the file with Preview and change the size of the file before you send it via message. From the Photo app you can export the photo as a jpeg say and then open it in Preview. Under the Annotate menu in Preview, you can save the size of the file. Once you decreased the size, you can then save it and send it using iMessage.

Comment: Preview is a Mac app, right?  This question is about iPhone.